# Formbuilder and angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm just getting started with angular material 2. 
So i started with `<md-form-filed>` .
I'm trying to use formBuilder inside .
Here goes my formBuilder code :

```
constructor(private _formBuilder : FormBuilder ) { 
    this.loginForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      'email' : [''],
      'password' : ['']
    }); 
 }
```

and in my html :

```
<md-card>
  <md-card-title>
    Login
  </md-card-title>
  <md-card-content>
    <ng-container>
      <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)='Login(f.value)'>
        <md-form-field >
          <input mdInput [formControl]="loginForm.controls['email']" placeholder='Email' required>
        </md-form-field>
      </form>
    </ng-container>
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

I'm getting this error in my console : **md-form-field must contain a MdFormFieldControl. Did you forget to add mdInput to the native input or textarea element?**

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Never mind guys . I forgot to import MdInputModule . Now its working fine .Sorry to bother you guys .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had initially not imported `MdInputModule` . After `import {MdInputModule} from '@angular/material` , the error stopped.